# Upgrade code from org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.websocket-client to org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.websocket-jakarta-client

Tags: spring-boot, jetty, jakarta-migration

I have the following application code in an application that I would like to migrate to Spring3 in order to do so javax is replaced with jakarta.

Any one have any Idea how to migrate the following code:

```java
// Let's create and start the Web Socket
//
// For internal test, we have a self-signed certificate. So we need to short cut certificate check.
// DO NOT DO THAT IN PRODUCTION!
boolean trustAll = (System.getProperty("com.graphql-java-generator.websocket.nosslcheck") != null);
org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.Client sslContextFactory = new org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.Client(
                trustAll);
org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(sslContextFactory);
org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient wsClient = new WebSocketClient(httpClient);
SubscriptionClientWebSocket<R, T> subscriptionClientWebSocket = new SubscriptionClientWebSocket<R, T>(request,
                subscriptionName, subscriptionCallback, subscriptionType, messageType,
                graphQLRequest.getGraphQLObjectMapper());
URI uri = getWebSocketURI();
try {
    wsClient.start();
    org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.ClientUpgradeRequest clientUpgradeRequest = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
    wsClient.connect(subscriptionClientWebSocket, uri, clientUpgradeRequest);
    logger.debug("Connecting to {}", uri);
} catch (Exception e) {
    String msg = "Error while opening the Web Socket connection to " + uri;
    logger.error(msg);
    throw new GraphQLRequestExecutionException(msg, e);
}
```

Having not found any documentation on how to proceed with this migration.

Tried using the JakartaWebSocketClientContainer but could not find how to use with an UpgradeRequest

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not using `javax.websocket`, so there's nothing to upgrade.

The techniques you are using in your code to manage the SSL behavior is also not possible in either `javax.websocket` or `jakarta.websocket` (There is no API you can use to manage SSL/TLS in those)